# let and const problems with visual studio and chrome

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a strange problem, google chrome won't read es6, like `let` or `const` or the new way to define a function inside an object.

If i used `var` it will work fine:

```
var cat = {
    name: 'meow',
    age: 5,
    eyeColor: 'black'
}
```

If i used `let` or `const` it won't work:

```
let cat = {
    name: 'meow',
    age: 5,
    eyeColor: 'black'
}
```

It gives me an error:

```
cat is not defined
```

Ok i figured something out, first of all here is my folder structure :

```
build 
  assets
     js
        app.js
        vendors.js

source
  js
     app.js
     vendors

gulpfile.js
```

I am writing all my code inside the source folder and gulp compile it to the build folder, here is my gulp file ( sorry its very long ) :

```
  // --------------------------------------------
  // Dependencies
  // --------------------------------------------
   var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
   concat = require('gulp-concat'),
   del = require('del'),
   gulp = require('gulp'),
   minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
   plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
   sass = require('gulp-sass'),
   sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
   rename = require('gulp-rename'),
   uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
   images = require('gulp-imagemin'),
   browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


   // paths
   var styleSrc = 'source/sass/**/*.sass',
   styleDest = 'build/assets/css/',
   htmlSrc = 'source/',
   htmlDest = 'build/',
   vendorSrc = 'source/js/vendors/',
   vendorDest = 'build/assets/js/',
   scriptSrc = 'source/js/*.js',
   scriptDest = 'build/assets/js/';



// --------------------------------------------
// Stand Alone Tasks
// --------------------------------------------


// Compiles all SASS files
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('source/sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            basename: 'main',
            suffix: '.min'
          }))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
    gulp.src('source/img/*')
        .pipe(images())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/img'));
});

// Uglify js files
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('source/js/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'));
});

//Concat and Compress Vendor .js files
gulp.task('vendors', function() {
    gulp.src(
            [
                'source/js/vendors/jquery.min.js',
                'source/js/vendors/*.js'
            ])
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'));
});



// Watch for changes
gulp.task('watch', function(){

    // Serve files from the root of this project
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build"
        },
        notify: false
    });

    gulp.watch(styleSrc,['sass']);
    gulp.watch(scriptSrc,['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(vendorSrc,['vendors']);
    gulp.watch(['build/*.html', 'build/assets/css/*.css', 'build/assets/js/*.js', 'build/assets/js/vendors/*.js']).on('change', browserSync.reload);

});


// use default task to launch Browsersync and watch JS files
gulp.task('default', [ 'sass', 'scripts', 'vendors', 'watch'], function () {});
```

When i write my code inside the build js file directly its working fine, but if i am writing my js inside the source folder it will only compile var, but if i tried let or const it won't

Comment: Please be more specific. Visual Studio Code? Which version? Which version of Chrome? What application shows that error message? Please add the complete code.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to retrieve the variable outside of its scope?

Comment: Let us know where in the code you declare the variable and where you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `let` has changed the scope of the variable `cat`. The error is not being generated at the declaration (bring up the Chrome console and paste your example to prove this to yourself).

The [MDN documentation for `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) says:

> The `let` statement declares a block scope local variable

Compare the given examples. Here's `let`:

```
let x = 1;

if (x === 1) {
    let x = 2;

    console.log(x);
    // expected output: 2
}

console.log(x);
// expected output: 1
```

And here's `var`:

```
var x = 1;

if (x === 1) {
    var x = 2;

    console.log(x);
    // expected output: 2
}

console.log(x);
// expected output: 2
```

Notice the difference in the first and second outputs from each example? In short, the error is actually in code that has not been shared yet. This example highlights the difference:

```
if (true) {
    var myVariable = 1;
    let myOtherVariable = 2;
}
console.log(myVariable);      //Outputs '1'
console.log(myOtherVariable); //Fails
```

Comment: nice clarification of var & let, & yeah OP needs to share his code.

Comment: the code is exactly as i shared it, my java script file is completely empty i am practicing objects was following a tutorial and it gave me this error,

i use the latest version or chrome and visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

Alright i fixed it just in case anybody had  this problem all you have to do is add babel to the watch task like so :

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/js/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'))
});
```